# Does this technique that deals with syllable meters have a name?

Tags: rhythm, songwriting

On the poem extract below I noticed the following technique and it sounded really familiar, reminding me of punk rock songs and some strong man speeches (I know this is super vague, if I remember any examples I'll link them in the comments). This technique consists of a metric progression of long verses to short verses culminating with a one or two syllable verse, which happens from verses 1 to 5 below, then this is followed by same metric length verses with Anaphoras, in this case it's an anaphora with "the". Does anyone know if this has a name?

1 Pretty women wonder where my secret lies.

2 I’m not cute or built to suit a fashion model’s size

3 But when I start to tell them,

4 They think I’m telling lies.

5 I say,

6 It’s in the reach of my arms,

7 The span of my hips,

8 The stride of my step,
-Phenomenal Woman, by: Maya Angelou

Comment: Maybe this should go on the Literature stack exchange, seems like its more of a poetry question than a music one.

Comment: It has gone in the literature stack exchange and they also redirected me

Comment: you probably have checked this link (but I couldn't find anything about the construction and term you are looking for: https://owlcation.com/humanities/Analysis-Of-Poem-Phenomenal-Woman-by-Maya-Angelou

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a rhythmic progression with a varied [meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry)).

Directly from [the article that Albrecht Hugli references in the comments](https://owlcation.com/humanities/Analysis-Of-Poem-Phenomenal-Woman-by-Maya-Angelou):

> There is a varied meter (metre in UK) in this poem, a mix of trochee
> and iamb with anapaest. The underlying beat in some lines is iambic,
> the well known da-DUM da-DUM da-DUM beat, the most common in English
> poetry...
>
> And others have trochaic followed by iambic...
>
> This variable
> rhythm, together with contrasting short and long vowels, make this a
> particularly interesting poem to read out loud and to listen to.

Modern poets like to break the rules which is arguably what gave rise to [Free Verse poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_verse) in the 19th century. So, there is likely no specific term that quantifies this technique other than "varied meter."

This is definitely a literary question so, I am not sure why on earth the literature stack exchange would have redirected you here...

Comment: Personally, I'm glad the question was posted here. It has given me something to think about as I  attempt music composition. I find rhythm to be important in the music that moves me.